# Calculation of log likelihood function of multinomial logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multinomial, log-likelihood

Suppose I have the following data set

```
df=data.frame(x1=rnorm(100), #predictor 1
              x2=rpois(100,2.5), #predictor 2
              x3=rgeom(100,prob = 0.48), #predictor 3
              y=as.factor(sample(1:3,100,replace = T)) #categorical response
              )
```

If I run the multinomial logistic regression by considering the `1` as the reference category, then the estimated parameters are

```
Call:
multinom(formula = y ~ ., data = df)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)         x1          x2         x3
2 -0.71018723 -0.4193710  0.15820110 0.05849252
3 -0.05987773 -0.2978596 -0.08335957 0.10149408
```

I would like to calculate the loglikelihood value of the multinomial logistic regression using these estimated parameters.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you just want the LL without doing any hard work, it is stored in the `value` element:  `nnet::multinom(y ~ ., data=df)$value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  The log-likelihood is just the sum of the log of the probabilities that each observation takes on its observed value.  In the code below `probs` is an *N x m* matrix of probabilities for each of the *N* observations on each of the *m* categories.  We can then get `y` from the model frame and turn it into a numeric variable which will indicate the category number.  We then use `cbind(1:length(y), y)` to index the probability matrix.  This makes an *N x 2* matrix that gives for each row number (in the first column) the column number of the `probs` matrix that you should keep.  So, `probs[cbind(1:length(y), y)]` creates a vector of probabilities that each observation takes on its observed *y* value.  We can log them and then sum them to get the log-likelihood.

```
df=data.frame(x1=rnorm(100), #predictor 1
              x2=rpois(100,2.5), #predictor 2
              x3=rgeom(100,prob = 0.48), #predictor 3
              y=as.factor(sample(1:3,100,replace = T)) #categorical response
)

mod <- nnet::multinom(formula = y ~ ., data = df)

probs <- predict(mod, type="probs")
y <- as.numeric(model.response(model.frame(mod)))
indiv_ll <- log(probs[cbind(1:length(y), y)])
sum(indiv_ll)
# [1] -106.8012
logLik(mod)
# 'log Lik.' -106.8012 (df=8)
```